# Why can't I add an object to a HashSet

Tags: java, hashset, bluej

I am trying to populate a HashSet in the constructor with Penny objects but I'm not really sure how to do this. I have written this but I keep getting error messages.

```
public Pocket(int numOfPennies){
    HashSet penniesSet = new HashSet<Penny>();

    while( penniesSet.size() <= numOfPennies){
        penniesSet.add(Penny);


}
```

Comment: In addition the issue mentioned below, you are declaring your set using a raw type. The correct form is `HashSet<Penny> penniesSet = new HashSet<Penny>()`, although with Java 7 you can avoid repeating `Penny` in the latter case: `HashSet<Penny> penniesSet = new HashSet<>()`.

Comment: (Actually, `Set<Penny> penniesSet = new HashSet<>()` is even better, in case you decide to switch to `TreeSet` later on.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not adding an object to the set but rather are trying to add a type, and this won't work or even compile. Instead of

```
penniesSet.add(Penny);
```

try

```
// assuming Penny has a default constructor
penniesSet.add(new Penny());
```

Also,

- Add to the collection using a for loop, not a while loop, since you know prior to starting the loop how many times that you want to loop.
- Are you sure you want to use a HashSet to hold your pennies? HashSets would be used when you want to have no duplicates in your collection, but wouldn't one Penny be equivalent to another? In other words, shouldn't this always be true: `pennyA.equals(pennyB)`. Of course this would depend on how you define `equals(...)` and `hashCode()` for your Penny class.
- Would a different collection such as an ArrayList be more logical?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I would use something else but I have to use a hashset as that is what I have been assigned to do. Sorry if my question was a bit rubbish I'm quite new to coding and this site so I don't quite get the rules and such...

Comment: Maybe each Penny is going to have a serial number?